# ListView with nested Expander not collapsing

Tags: wpf, listview, expander

This question is the same as this other [unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1381336/cant-get-wpf-listview-to-collapse-when-expanders-in-the-listview-collapse).

When the *Expander* is expanded the outer *ListView* grows to make space for the expanders contents, but when the *Expander* is then collapsed the view does not force the ListView to resize.

Reduced code, with notes after:

```
<!--<StackPanel>-->
<ItemsControl>

  <!-- ParameterGroupView -->
  <Border BorderBrush="Brown" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="4" Padding="4">
    <ListView HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
      <Expander Header="Expander A" IsExpanded="False">
        <ListView HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">

          <!-- TextView -->
          <TextBlock >Content A</TextBlock>
          <TextBlock >Content B</TextBlock>

        </ListView>
      </Expander>

    </ListView>
  </Border>

</ItemsControl>
<!--</StackPanel>-->
```

I have the *ParameterGroupView* in a *ItemsControl* or *StackPanel* because there is actually many *ParameterGroupView* entries. Swapping to a *StackPanel* does not change the behaviour.

Removing the *Boarder* does not affect the behaviour, but having it helps show the behaviour with only a single *ParameterGroupView*.

There can be many *Expander* sections in the outer *ListView*, and the *Expander* can have many entities inside the inner *ListView*.

The outer *ListView* and *Expander* is to replace a *TreeView*, that was used to have a list of collapsible nodes, but the *TreeView*'s internal use of grids, means the TextView items were squashed horizonatlly, the same as if you remove ether *HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"* attributes.

So if there is another way to wrap/wire all this up, I'll be also happy.

This is a problem because our *TextView* blocks are large and there are many *Expander*s.

Edit: *TextView* is used as the code is data-bound, and thus dynamically put together. So any replacement for ListView would need some form of *ItemsSource*

Comment: I also didn't want any of the ListView style interaction with the content items. I really just wanted a dynamic resizing control that could be bound too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the solution, and it details where in the question already.

*ItemControl* accepts an *ItemsSource* and auto resizes. So replacing the two *ListView*s with *ItemControl*s gets the nested collapsing.

But there is no scrolling, so wrapping the outer *ItemControl* with a *ScrollViewer*, reproduces the complete desired effect.

```
<ScrollViewer
    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <ItemsControl>
        <!-- ParameterGroupView -->
        <Border
            BorderBrush="Brown"
            BorderThickness="1"
            CornerRadius="4"
            Padding="4"
            Height="Auto">
            <ItemsControl
                HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
                <Expander
                    Header="Expander A"
                    IsExpanded="False">
                    <ItemsControl
                        HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
                        <!-- TextView -->
                        <TextBlock>Content A</TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock>Content B</TextBlock>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </Expander>
            </ItemsControl>
        </Border>
    </ItemsControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

I was testing with double Expanders in the Border and double Border sections.

Comment: Just tested this in the actual application, and this solves the problem there also.

Answer (score 2):

The most obvious thing to do here is to put the expanders in a container other than a listview:

```
<Border BorderBrush="Brown" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="4" Padding="4">
    <StackPanel>

        <Expander Header="Expander A" IsExpanded="False">
            <ListView HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" MinWidth="100">
                <ListBox Name="listb"></ListBox>

                <!-- TextView -->
                <TextBlock >Content A</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock>Content B</TextBlock>

            </ListView>
        </Expander>
    </StackPanel>
</Border>
```

The container resizes around content just fine.

If you absolutely must have it in a ListView (which is possible) then I don't know of a way to get a ListView to resize easily once it's grown (beyond setting explicit sizes of the whole thing, which is clumsy and not useful). If thats the case then it's possible that you'll have to use a controllable listbox to display all the open expanders, or display the content in a different way (like in a popup, maybe?) if you want to be able to see it all at a glance.

Comment: Yes, I agree the ListBox is at fault, but I need it, or something like it, as it supports ItemsSource, where-as the StackPanel does not. My actual system is complete data bound, not static.